# Android AsyncTask how to check if it was launched with a specific arg

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I get data asynchrounsly and this data gets plotted,
got the logic worked out and now of course I need to run this smootthly
so I use an AsyncTask when I get more data it is digested  to a bitmap and plotted accordingly
of course running on a loop without the AsyncTask works but on slower/older devices it is slugish, with the ASyncTask it seems like there is some sort of overrun as the bitmap/ImageView flickers

The items come in 5 different flavours so I set my parms properly when I make a new instance of the Asynctask and call execute to run a new instance of it

Now if a particular task for a specific flavour is running already how to check
that??? so that I skip it until it finish processing the data for that type??? I needed to pass different data types so I used a list of Objects and that works

I know KISS is to make 5 different instances of the AsyncTask and check the 
**taskInstance_n.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING**
but I thought there may be a cleaner/cooler generic way to do it ????

```
    ArrayList<Object>parms = new ArrayList<Object>
    ...
    do
    {
      ..grab the data ...
      switch(id)
      {
        case 0:
                 parms.clear();
                 parms.add(arg1);
                 parms.add((type1)arg2)
                 parms.add((type2)arg3)
                 if( ! task is running with arg1)  ---->how do I do this
                    new myAsyncTask().execute(parms,null,null);

              break;
        case 1:
        ... other 4 choices simar way to call it
      }  // end of switch

      ...

  }while(i_get_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to a popular belief, AsyncTasks don't run in parallel, they form a queue and wait for each other (except in HoneyComb, but you should not target API9-10 anyway). So you should not worry about two AsyncTasks working on the same type of data, when you get something new, prepare the parameters and fire away, it will patiently wait until all previous AsyncTasks are completed anyway.

Comment: Parallel or not my problem is that it comes around while the 1st task was still running and I'm trying to catch that to skip it. the blinking/blanking of the bitmap  tells me some overrun is happening there.

Comment: you may add `:pg()` calls to your `AsyncTasks` to make sure there's no overrun and only one is running at any given moment of time. why your bitmap is blinking is, most probably, a totally different problem.

Comment: I haven't double check that but If I run in a loop is fine just slow I'm trying to run a few of these tasks not just one since for differnt data I plot differently just trying to avoid the one that is still runnig already if it is.

Comment: After much trying I found out the AsyncTask was not  gonna cut it I could make it work but it was too tweaky  for this little excersize. What worked was a Thread handling it out just like the SurfaceView handles the drawing. The SurfaceView itself didn't help me because I needed these little graphs to be scrollable by the user and that  didnt work out for me neither but I got the Thread idea from there and now it is unbelievable responsive and smooth even on older 2.3 units.